# BioPython to write a program for a PubMed query

Tags: python, biopython, pubmed

I have to ask the user for a query and then get print the number of matches, and the Title, First Author Name, Last Author Name for the first 5 returned results.

What I have so far:

```
from Bio import Entrez
from Bio import Medline

pmquery = str(input("Enter the Pubmed query:"))
Entrez.email = "myemailadress@bdm.com"
handle = Entrez.esearch(db="pubmed", term=pmquery,retmax=5)
record = Entrez.read(handle)
handle.close()
print(record)
```

Comment: Is there a question?

Answer (score 0):

The results you store in record should be a dictionary or list of dictionaries. You can access it for example like:

```
for entry in record:
    print(entry["Title"])
```

to get the titles of your results. Access the fields for the info you want (print the whole dict to see what they are called) accordingly and restrict your loop to 5 iterations.